# Can I see which Games With Gold games for Xbox One I've acquired, without an Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, digital-distribution

I don't have an Xbox One, but I do have an Xbox 360 and an Xbox Live Gold account. Every month since it began, I've been collecting the [Games with Gold](http://www.xbox.com/LIVE/games-with-gold) for both platforms on the off-chance that I eventually upgrade to an Xbox One.  But so far, of course, I've never downloaded any of the XB1-only titles.

I can easily check which Xbox 360 games I've acquired this way, including any that haven't actually downloaded yet, via the [Download History](https://live.xbox.com/download/history) page on the Xbox Live website. But this only shows Xbox 360 and PC titles. Is there any similar way to see what Xbox One games I've acquired, without having any access to an Xbox One?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that download link you have in your question, on the top right of the page you will see "My Xbox."  Click it, and select "[My Games](https://account.xbox.com/en-US/MyGames?xr=shellnav)."  This will show you all the games you own for both Xbox One, and Xbox 360.  For you, all your Xbox One games should only be the Games with Gold games since that's all you've ever purchased.

Comment: D'oh, can't believe I've never noticed that before. Thanks.